# Whatsapp Click to Chat link openning in AppStore when URL shortener used

Tags: ios, safari, ios-appstore, url, whatsapp.app

When SMS with shortened *Click to Chat* URL for WhatsApp is received on the iPhone, clicking it leads me to the App Store instead of opening chat in WhatsApp, despite WhatsApp being installed on the device.

When the same delivery method is used (SMS), but the URL isn't shortened, it works as expected.

I tested various URL shorteners and it doesn't work with any.

Has anyone ran into a similar problem and how did they solve it? Googling is unfortunately not giving any results that would cover issues with this use case.

iOS 12.3.1, latest WhatsApp version on iPhone X 256GB.

Comment: What happens if you copy paste it in Safari?

Comment: It gives the same result, leads to AppStore to install (already installed app)

Comment: I tried https://bitly.com and the url expanded and "tried" to open WhatsApp.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii which iOS version and did you manage to open chat?

Comment: Same as yours on SE. Okay wait! I thought if I tap open, it would work. But it redirected me to App Store too after opening WhatsApp momentarily. Please add this in the question: the *momentarily* part

Comment: We discovered a way to use “whatsapp://“ instead of click to chat api url. It works as expected.

Comment: Oh great! Better purge the comments and you close the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'whatsapp://' prefix instead of Click to Chat URL will work properly on both iOS and Android devices.